# Upgrading from Python to 2.7.10 to 2.7.11 on OSX

Tags: macos, python, osx-yosemite

How can I upgrade Python from 2.7.10 to 2.7.11 on OSX (Yosemite)?

Comment: Isnt python already on 3.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not replace the Python version that comes with OS X. If you do, you may break something in your system. Instead, you should install a new instance of Python.

You could use [brew](http://brew.sh) whenever they are offering 2.7.11:

```
brew install python
```

However, it is likely that they still only offer 2.7.10. In that case, you can download the [source code](https://www.python.org/downloads/source/) and compile it yourself. Unpack into a directory and run:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/python2.7.11 && make && make install
```

Answer (score 3):

`brew install python@2`

You can install python 2 version this

(It will take only latest 2.7.X version)

`brew install python`

will install python 3.